# Using WITH statement in dynamic query

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-9.2

How to use `WITH` statement in dynamic query? for example, what is right syntax for something like this:

```
// begin function
DECLARE my_var INTEGER;

EXECUTE   'WITH a AS ( SELECT 4 )';

EXECUTE    'SELECT * from a' INTO  my_var;

RETURN my_var;
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something more like:

```
EXECUTE 'WITH a AS ( SELECT 4 ) SELECT * from a' INTO  my_var;
```

Don't forget the `BEGIN` and `END`, too.

```
create function foo() returns bar as $$
DECLARE
  ...
BEGIN
  ...
END; $$ language plpgsql;
```